# Unity 2D: WaitForSeconds() delay isn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add a delay between `player.healthDisplay.color = Color.green;` and `player.healthDisplay.color = Color.white;` but at the moment `yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);` and
`player.healthDisplay.color = Color.white;` aren't working.

Here's my code:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(ColorChange());           
    }
}

IEnumerator ColorChange()
{
    player.health++;
    Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    Destroy(gameObject);
    player.healthDisplay.color = Color.green;
    //until here code the code is working

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
                         
    player.healthDisplay.color = Color.white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destroying the gameobject which has this script on it.

```
Destroy(gameObject);
// color changing code, etc..
```

Once the gameobject has been destroyed this script will no longer run.

What you can do instead (if you need this gameobject to be destroyed immediately) is add a script to health display that will handle the color change.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the `MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine` documentation which says:

"Coroutines are also stopped when the MonoBehaviour is destroyed or if the GameObject the MonoBehaviour is attached to is disabled. Coroutines are not stopped when a MonoBehaviour is disabled." [[Ref](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)]

So a simple fix for this:

```
IEnumerator ColorChange()
{
    player.health++;
    Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
    player.healthDisplay.color = Color.green;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
                     
    player.healthDisplay.color = Color.white;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

If you wonder why the `player.healthDisplay.color = Color.green` still work.

"Actual object destruction is always delayed until after the current Update loop, but is always done before rendering." [[Ref](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)]